# even.data is not change

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my own practice [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/player889/vP7rN/3/), it works well as i expect. but when i use line 8 ( comment on my demo code ) instead of line 7 ,the input text values all change to 0 which is different than the result of demo i giving out.

i look at the jquery website it only gives me this

> Description: An optional object of data passed to an event method when the current executing handler is bound.

i think the result of using line 8 or line 7 should be the same because  of i is assigned to count object, but it is not. Could someone explain me about this question. by the way, if someone could refactor my code will be even more nicer THANKS!!

here is my code

```
var i = 0;
$("#aa").on("click", {
    count : i       
}, 
function(event) {
    var div = $('<div/>');
    var input = $('<input />').attr("value", event.data.count);
    event.data.count++;
    //i++;
        var bt = $('<input />').attr({
            type : "button",
            value : "remove",
        });
        div.append(input);
        div.append(bt);

        var index = $("div").length;
        if (index == 0) {
            $("#aa").after(div);
        } else {
            $("div").last().after(div);
        }

        bt.on('click', function(event) {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
when the current executing handler is bound.
```

this is important thing in the section. So, the object will be created only once, during the time of binding the function with the `click` event. So, changing `i` will not change the value of `event.data`.

When you do

```
event.data.count++;
```

you are actually mutating the object and the state of the object will be retained. That is why it works.